# Use name of referenced object as argument of string comparison

Tags: cross-referencing, expl3, nameref

I have argument `#1` which contains some text *X* representing some label.
I would like to use `\str_if_eq` to compare *X* and name of paragraph referenced by this string. What I want to achieve is that if `\label{X}` is under some `\paragraph[shortname_different_from_X]{Long description}`, I want to include `\nameref{X}`, so that reader would see *shortname_different_from_X*, so that it would be possible to find what I'm talking about also in printed version. (Assume knowing *shortname_different_from_X* is enough to find correct paragraph in printed version.)

Here is my code:

```
\cs_new_protected:Nn \mynode_print:N
 {
  \texttt
   {
    \tl_if_empty:NTF #1
      { - }
      { \hyperref[\tl_to_str:N #1] { \tl_to_str:N #1} % this is here only to show name of label and make it so that reader can click on it and go to label
      \str_if_eq:nnTF{\tl_to_str:N #1}{ \nameref{\tl_to_str:N #1} }{}{ ~(see~\nameref{\tl_to_str:N #1}) } } % second argument should be changed so that it contains name of referenced paragraph
   };~
 }
```

In provided code, comparison returns always `false`, because using `\nameref{\tl_to_str:N #1}` in second argument of `str_if_eq` is wrong, it's not a string.

For completeness, here is usage example, I don't want `see n_1`, `see n_2`, `see n_3` visible, only `see missing_nodes` should be visible:

```
\documentclass[12pt, oneside]{book}
\usepackage[a4paper,top=2.5cm,bottom=2.5cm,left=3.5cm,right=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[IL2]{fontenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{url}
\DeclareUrlCommand\url{\def\UrlLeft{<}\def\UrlRight{>} \urlstyle{tt}}
\usepackage[hidelinks,breaklinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage[slovak]{babel}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{fancyvrb}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{dot2texi}
\usepackage{nameref}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{xstring}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\usetikzlibrary{snakes,arrows,shapes}
\linespread{1.25}
\setlength{\emergencystretch}{30pt}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand\mynode{mmmm}
 {
  \mynode_main:nnnn { #1 } { #2 } { #3 } { #4 }
 }

\seq_new:N \l_mynode_input_seq
\seq_new:N \l_mynode_output_seq
\tl_new:N \l_mynode_node_tl
\tl_new:N \l_mynode_text_tl

\cs_new_protected:Nn \mynode_main:nnnn
 {
  \seq_set_split:Nnn \l_mynode_input_seq { ; } { #3 }
  \seq_set_split:Nnn \l_mynode_output_seq { ; } { #4 }
  \tl_set:Nn \l_mynode_node_tl { #1 }
  \mynode_replace:N \l_mynode_node_tl
  \tl_set:Nn \l_mynode_text_tl { #2 }
  \mynode_replace:N \l_mynode_text_tl

  \mynode_paragraph:VV \l_mynode_node_tl \l_mynode_text_tl
  \label{ \tl_to_str:n { #1 } }

  \begin{itemize}
    \item in:~
    \seq_map_variable:NNn \l_mynode_input_seq \l_mynode_node_tl
     {
      \mynode_print:N \l_mynode_node_tl
     }
    \item out:~
    \seq_map_variable:NNn \l_mynode_output_seq \l_mynode_node_tl
     {
      \mynode_print:N \l_mynode_node_tl
     }
  \end{itemize}
 }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \mynode_paragraph:nn
 {
  \paragraph[#1]{#2~(\texttt{#1}):}
 }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \mynode_paragraph:nn { VV }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \mynode_print:N
 {
  \texttt
   {
    \tl_if_empty:NTF #1
      { - }
      { \hyperref[\tl_to_str:N #1] { \tl_to_str:N #1}
      \str_if_eq:nnTF{\tl_to_str:N #1}{ \nameref{\tl_to_str:N #1} }{}{ ~(see~\nameref{\tl_to_str:N #1}) } }
   };~
 }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \mynode_replace:N
 {
  \regex_replace_all:nnN { \_ } { \c{_} } #1
  \regex_replace_all:nnN { \< } { \c{textless} } #1
  \regex_replace_all:nnN { \> } { \c{textgreater} } #1
 }

\NewDocumentCommand{\change}{m}
 {
  \tl_set:Nn \l_mynode_text_tl { #1 }
  \mynode_replace:N \l_mynode_text_tl
  \tl_use:N \l_mynode_text_tl
\tl_show_analysis:N #1
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff


\begin{document}     
\mynode{n_1}{node 1}{}{n_2;n_3}
\mynode{n_2}{node 2}{n_1}{n_4}
\mynode{n_3}{node 3}{n_1}{}
\paragraph[missing\_nodes]{Nodes that are not present}
Some text describing why nodes are missing.
\label{n_4}
\label{n_5}
% ...

\end{document}
```

Comment: Can you please make your code compilable with an example usage?

Comment: I added example code. There may be some unused `\usepackage` commands, I took it from long document. I can try to shorten it more if it's needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There you go!

The first problem was that you were using `\str_if_eq:nn` instead of `\str_if_eq:ee`. The former, when you pass an argument like `\tl_to_str:N #1` will compare the literal text “\tl_to_str:N#1” (with the proper replacement of `#1` by the actual argument), and will not expand `\tl_to_str:N`. But once you change that, then `\nameref` will explode because it's not expandable. I loaded the `refcount` package and used `\getrefbykeydefault`, which is expandable. And the final problem was that you were doing the substitution of `_` by `\_` too early, and then the label would be saved as `n\_1` but would compare against `n_1`. I moved the `\mynode_replace:N` before the actual typesetting, which is where you will need the replacement.

I removed the unused packages for the example. Note that `hyperref` should be the very last package to be loaded, except for very few exceptions (lovely sentence, this one :).

On June 2018 the `\str_if_eq_x:nn` function was renamed to `\str_if_eq:eeTF`, so if you have an older `expl3` it won't work. I added a check for that so that the code will use which one is available.

Here's the output:

> [image]

and the code:

```latex
\documentclass[12pt, oneside]{book}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{refcount}
\usepackage[hidelinks,breaklinks]{hyperref}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand\mynode{mmmm}
 {
   \mynode_main:nnnn { #1 } { #2 } { #3 } { #4 }
 }

\seq_new:N \l_mynode_input_seq
\seq_new:N \l_mynode_output_seq
\tl_new:N \l_mynode_node_tl
\tl_new:N \l_mynode_text_tl

\cs_new_protected:Nn \mynode_main:nnnn
 {
  \seq_set_split:Nnn \l_mynode_input_seq { ; } { #3 }
  \seq_set_split:Nnn \l_mynode_output_seq { ; } { #4 }
  \tl_set:Nn \l_mynode_node_tl { #1 }
  \tl_set:Nn \l_mynode_text_tl { #2 }

  \mynode_paragraph:VV \l_mynode_node_tl \l_mynode_text_tl
  \label{ \tl_to_str:n { #1 } }

  \begin{itemize}
    \item in:~
    \seq_map_variable:NNn \l_mynode_input_seq \l_mynode_node_tl
     {
      \mynode_print:N \l_mynode_node_tl
     }
    \item out:~
    \seq_map_variable:NNn \l_mynode_output_seq \l_mynode_node_tl
     {
      \mynode_print:N \l_mynode_node_tl
     }
  \end{itemize}
 }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \mynode_paragraph:nn
 {
   \tl_set:Nn \l_tmpa_tl {#1}
   \mynode_replace:N \l_tmpa_tl
   \paragraph[#1]{#2~(\texttt{\l_tmpa_tl}):}
 }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \mynode_paragraph:nn { VV }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \mynode_print:N
 {
  \texttt
   {
    \tl_if_empty:NTF #1
      { - }
      {
        \tl_set:Nx #1 { \tl_to_str:N #1 } % To avoid repetition
        \hyperref [#1] {#1}
        \cs_if_exist_use:NF \str_if_eq:eeTF \str_if_eq_x:nnTF
        % \str_if_eq:eeTF
            {#1}
            { \getrefbykeydefault {#1} { name } { squirdshlicker~:) } }
          {}
          { ~(see~\nameref{#1}) }
      }
   };~
 }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \mynode_replace:N
 {
  \regex_replace_all:nnN { \_ } { \c{_} } #1
  \regex_replace_all:nnN { \< } { \c{textless} } #1
  \regex_replace_all:nnN { \> } { \c{textgreater} } #1
 }

\NewDocumentCommand{\change}{m}
 {
  \tl_set:Nn \l_mynode_text_tl { #1 }
  \mynode_replace:N \l_mynode_text_tl
  \tl_use:N \l_mynode_text_tl
\tl_show_analysis:N #1
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
\mynode{n_1}{node 1}{}{n_2;n_3}
\mynode{n_2}{node 2}{n_1}{n_4}
\mynode{n_3}{node 3}{n_1}{}
\paragraph[missing\_nodes]{Nodes that are not present}
Some text describing why nodes are missing.
\label{n_4}
\label{n_5}

\end{document}
```

On your second request. Yes, it is possible, but not recommended. I made a macro to do that, but please notice that the `:D` argument specification means “Do not use”!

There is one major issue that makes this a weird thing: the material in the optional argument of `\paragraph` (or any other sectioning command, for that matter) is supposed to be typesettable material, so you *should* escape the `_`.

I used the least awkward approach to do this: I make a copy of the label into a temporary macro, then I apply `\mynode_replace:N` to said label, and then call `\nameref` to do its thing with the now escaped label. Finally I restore the label to its original value.

Full code (the output is the same):

```latex
\documentclass[12pt, oneside]{book}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{refcount}
\usepackage[hidelinks,breaklinks]{hyperref}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand\mynode{mmmm}
 {
   \mynode_main:nnnn { #1 } { #2 } { #3 } { #4 }
 }

\seq_new:N \l_mynode_input_seq
\seq_new:N \l_mynode_output_seq
\tl_new:N \l_mynode_node_tl
\tl_new:N \l_mynode_text_tl

\cs_new_protected:Nn \mynode_main:nnnn
 {
  \seq_set_split:Nnn \l_mynode_input_seq { ; } { #3 }
  \seq_set_split:Nnn \l_mynode_output_seq { ; } { #4 }
  \tl_set:Nn \l_mynode_node_tl { #1 }
  \tl_set:Nn \l_mynode_text_tl { #2 }

  \mynode_paragraph:VV \l_mynode_node_tl \l_mynode_text_tl
  \label{ \tl_to_str:n { #1 } }

  \begin{itemize}
    \item in:~
    \seq_map_variable:NNn \l_mynode_input_seq \l_mynode_node_tl
     {
      \mynode_print:N \l_mynode_node_tl
     }
    \item out:~
    \seq_map_variable:NNn \l_mynode_output_seq \l_mynode_node_tl
     {
      \mynode_print:N \l_mynode_node_tl
     }
  \end{itemize}
 }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \mynode_paragraph:nn
 {
   \tl_set:Nn \l_tmpa_tl {#1}
   \mynode_replace:N \l_tmpa_tl
   \paragraph[#1]{#2~(\texttt{\l_tmpa_tl}):}
 }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \mynode_paragraph:nn { VV }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \mynode_print:N
 {
  \texttt
   {
    \tl_if_empty:NTF #1
      { - }
      {
        \tl_set:Nx #1 { \tl_to_str:N #1 } % To avoid repetition
        \hyperref [#1] {#1}
        \cs_if_exist_use:NF \str_if_eq:eeTF \str_if_eq_x:nnTF
        % \str_if_eq:eeTF
            {#1}
            { \getrefbykeydefault {#1} { name } { squirdshlicker~:) } }
          {}
          {
            \exp_args:NV
            \__mynode_label_bodge:D #1 { ~(see~\nameref{#1}) }
          }
      }
   };~
 }

\cs_new_protected:Npn \__mynode_label_bodge:D #1 #2
  {
    \cs_set_eq:Nc \__mynode_tmpa: { r@#1 }
    \exp_args:Nc
    \mynode_replace:N { r@#1 }
    #2
    \cs_set_eq:cN { r@#1 } \__mynode_tmpa:
  }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \mynode_replace:N
 {
  \regex_replace_all:nnN { \_ } { \c{_} } #1
  \regex_replace_all:nnN { \< } { \c{textless} } #1
  \regex_replace_all:nnN { \> } { \c{textgreater} } #1
 }

\NewDocumentCommand{\change}{m}
 {
  \tl_set:Nn \l_mynode_text_tl { #1 }
  \mynode_replace:N \l_mynode_text_tl
  \tl_use:N \l_mynode_text_tl
\tl_show_analysis:N #1
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
\mynode{n_1}{node 1}{}{n_2;n_3}
\mynode{n_2}{node 2}{n_1}{n_4}
\mynode{n_3}{node 3}{n_1}{}
\paragraph[missing_nodes]{Nodes that are not present}
Some text describing why nodes are missing.
\label{n_4}
\label{n_5}

\end{document}
```

Comment: @user224348 It looks like you have an older `expl3` which doesn't have `\str_if_eq:eeTF` ([added on June 2018](https://github.com/latex3/latex3/commit/8fcb571ddda61c01773d9746d32cecdbe63afb26#diff-3bd0e1d3b9a942f7e746cdcecb0e8fdb)) and you are probably getting a bunch of compilation errors. I added a version which should work with your version of `expl3`.

Comment: Can I have one more question to this code? In `\mynode_paragraph:nn` I used that trick with temp variable also on `#2` so that it would be escaped too. Can I use something similar if I didn't escape `missing\_nodes`? I have realized that it would maybe make more sense to not escape it if everything else is not escaped (for example I could use `mynode` and `paragraph` interchangeably).

Comment: @user224348 I added a variant. However I think you _should_ escape the underscore there because it is supposed to be typesettable material. If you want you can create a dedicated macro which handles that in a less awkward way :-)